# WAMP, Laravel 5: Routes not working - NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

I'm using Laravel 5 with WAMP on my local machine, no virtualization. After creating a fresh project using Composer called "LaravelProject", I can't seem to get my routes working at all. What I've already done:

- Edited httpd.conf to uncomment the line

  > LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
- Edited the /public/.htaccess file to be

  > Options +FollowSymLinks 
  >   RewriteEngine On
  >   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  >   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  >   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
- Refreshed WAMP
- **"localhost/laravelproject/public"** works
- **"localhost/laravelproject/public/index.php/signup"** works
- **"localhost/laravelproject/public/signup"** throws the NotFoundHttpException

The error:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161
```

routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get('/signup', function() {
    return view('auth.signup');
});
```

All other questions I've found say that it's an .htaccess and mod_rewrite problem, but I have already tried those solutions. This is a completely fresh installation, the only extra file is the signup.blade.php view. Please help!

Comment: Are you sure you have the folder auth and signup.blade.php?

Comment: Yep, it's in app/resources/views/auth/signup.blade.php.

Comment: Can i see the folder structure?

Comment: Just run `tree` from command prompt

Comment: Whoops, here it is: [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1THj-ZFqo_DoK5-c6uYvdG2wI-Vux_LlN2WfcxTU3mpA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Did a complete reinstall of WAMP, same result... considering trying XAMPP.

Comment: Have you created a Virtual Host  for this site to run in? [See this for how to create Virtual Hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: Has anyone found this, I decided to go with Vagrant and Homestead instead and it works fine, but might not have been necessary

Comment: Ahh, tried everything and not even Laragon worked, so I give up. I think it's my machine itself, something's wonky but I just don't know what.