# Laravel 5 - Routes error: NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel-5

Similar to the unsolved 
[WAMP, Laravel 5: Routes not working - NotFoundHttpException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116498/wamp-laravel-5-routes-not-working-notfoundhttpexception)

I am trying to pick up Laravel but the routes do not work at all (save for '/').

Using WAMP on Windows 7, I have done the following already in an attempt to rectify the situation;

**Enabled** `rewrite_module`

**My .htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**My routes.php:**

```
<?php

Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@contact');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
});
```

**My PagesController.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function contact()
    {
        return 'Test Contact';
    }
}
```

When I go to the aliased http://localhost/laravel.dev/ it shows the landing page, but when I navigate to http://localhost/laravel.dev/contact it returns:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 802
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 670
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 654
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I have been reading up on and attempting solutions for days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /laravel.dev/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy codding!

Comment: i have exactly the same problem at my place, but this htaccess file does not work for me. All of my custom routes are working, but not the one i try to implement at the moment - i did everything exactly the way i did it before...but i only receive that NotFoundHttpException - what could it be? i've been searching for 2 days now...